# In jackson's custom JsonSerializer , how to correctly set View?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonserializer

I have an `UserBean` , which stores some user field , and another `viewer` field , indicating who is reading this `UserBean`.

In this `UserBean` , I define a custom JsonSerializer :

```
@JsonSerialize(using = UserBeanSerializer.class)
public class UserBean {
  @JsonIgnore
  private User viewer;

  @JsonIgnore
  Private User user;

  @JsonView(Views.Private.class)
  public String getEmail() { return user.getEmail(); }      

  // other user fields
}
```

And in the UserBeanSerializer :

```
public class UserBeanSerializer extends JsonSerializer<UserBean> {

  @Override
  public void serialize(UserBean userBean, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Class view;
    if (Objects.equals(userBean.getViewer(), userBean.getUser()))
      view = Views.Private.class;
    else
      view = Views.Public.class;

    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
      .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
      .writerWithView(view)
      .writeValue(jgen, userBean);
  }
}
```

In the custom serializer , I check if the `viewer` equals the `user` . If so , the view is Private , otherwise Public.

It seems OK , but the code `writeValue` will recursively call the `UserBeanSerializer` , causing `StackOverflowError` . How to avoid this ?

BTW , it seems I cannot reuse `ObjectMapper` or inject guice-defined `Provider<ObjectMapper>` (because `UserBeanSerializer` is initialized by jackson) . Is there anyway to overcome this ?

Comment: Has `UserBean` a field of `UserBean` type without `@JsonIgnore`?

Comment: Hi . no. UserBean doesn't have any field with type UserBean.